# Oracle Hirerachical Query

Tags: oracle

I want to write oracle hirerachical   query which would return parent value if child has no value.If child has value it should return child value only. If child has no value it has to traverse until its one parent has value.

```
 Select *  From (
      Select Orgid,Text       
      From (
            Select Cusid,parent_id, Orgid, Rownum R          
            FROM (
               SELECT cus.customerid cusid, org.Id orgid,
                      cus.customername, org.parent_id          
               From Boms_Customer Cus, Boms_Organization Org          
               Where Cus.Organization_Id=Org.Id
           ) A          
           START WITH a.cusid=100
           Connect By Prior A.Parent_Id = A.Orgid
     ) X,        
     (
        Select Org.Organization_Id,Org.Text    
        From FORTRESS.SUPPORT_QUESTION org 
     ) Y          
     WHERE x.orgid = y.ORGANIZATION_ID ORDER BY x.r
)
```

But my query is returning all parents data and child data.Please help me inquery getting only childrens data if it has data otherwise it should return parents data.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with a bit of work here is what I get:

```
with organisation(id, parent_id, name) as
(
  select 1, null, 'Cisco' from dual
  union all
  select 2, 1, 'vodafone' from dual
  union all
  select 22, 1, 'SFR' from dual
  union all
  select 3, 1, 'Airtel' from dual
  union all
  select 4, 2, 'Aircel' from dual
),
question(ID, ORG_ID, QName) as
(
  select 1, 1, 'Test' from dual
  union all
  select 2, 1, 'XYZ' from dual
  union all
  select 3, 2, 'Testing Network' from dual
),
have_question(org_id) as
(
  select distinct org_id from question
),
tree as
(
  select o.*, level lev, sys_connect_by_path(id, '/') path
  from organisation o
  connect by parent_id = prior id
  start with parent_id is null
),
ancestors as
(
  select t.id, t2.id ancestor, t2.lev ancestor_lev
  from tree t, tree t2, have_question h
  where t.path || '/' like t2.path || '/%'
    and h.org_id (+) = t2.id
    and h.org_id is not null
)
select a.id, max(ancestor) keep (dense_rank last order by ancestor_lev) first_ancestor_with_question
from ancestors a
group by a.id
order by 1
;
```

You only have to do a join with question table to get the corresponding questions.

Comment: But i want code in generic with out any hard coding  parameters like u have done cisco vodafone .Please help me in writing generic code

Comment: Your comment proves that you don't understand much in SQL - the `with` clause is just a trick to simulate using a table. You definitely have to understand first and make a little effort before asking questions on this forum.